# Prestashop Web-API Limit in combination with sort always returning the same

Tags: rest, api, web-services, prestashop

I'm currently working on a project that uses the Prestashop Web-API to get products. If I now want to get 5 lowest-priced items, I use this URL:

```
http://mystore.com/api/products&output_format=JSON&display=full&limit=5&sort=[price_ASC]
```

That works perfectly fine.

But if I now want have just the second cheapest I tried add the `limit=[2,1]` argument but this always seems to return the cheapest items even if I set `limit=[10000,1]` I always get the same item.

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to load all my items and then continue from there?

Comment: you don't need to pass limit in [2,1] square bracket use simply limit = 2,1 seprated with comma